# Как скрыть клавиатуру telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, клавиатура

как можно скрыть клавиатуру пользователю после нажатия кнопки или ввода текста.

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg, reply_markup=NONE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На ответ пользователя допишите `reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()` в `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '_')`

Полный код:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '_', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```

Таким образом клавиатура удалится полностью для пользователя, но клавиатуру по прежнему можно будет вызвать обратившись к ей.

Пример:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '_', reply_markup=keyboard1)
```

Comment: а как можно ее не удалять, а скрыть временно? hide вместо remove

Answer (score 0):

спасибо сначала делал как ты просил но кнопка не исчезла исчезло только окошко призыва кнопки но как только убрал one_time_keyboard=True то все заработало как надо